# how to remove hasToolTip?

Tags: jquery

Ok, I have this code that's auto-generated and ***absolutely*** no idea where it's coming from and it's seriously causing issues.

And I'm so tired of it cause I've tried figuring out all the files but it's modifying serious core files that I shouldn't be modifying ...

Here's the code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(document).ready(function()
        {
            jQuery('.hasTooltip').tooltip({"container": false});
        });
</script>
```

How do I use jQuery to defang it????

I know that there is removeClass but you have to have a selector to use it ...

My jQuery isn't good enough to know how to remove it without selector ...

Any help to figure out the right jQuery code to write it so, even when it's auto-generated, it's rendered inffective?

Any help would be seriously so helpful. More than words could express.

EDIT

Ok, is this how I write it up?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".deeper").addClass("has-dropdown");
  jQuery("ul li ul").addClass("dropdown");


  jQuery("ul").removeClass("nav");
  jQuery("ul").removeClass("menu");

  $(document).find('.hasTooltip').removeClass('.hasTooltip');

});
</script>
```

EDIT Two

To clarify, the reason why I asked for getting rid of hasTooltip in the first place is that menu of the site gets screwed up.

If you view the page under normal circumstances, it's fine.

If you use the search button, and type in a word that the site can find, ie, "social services", the menu gets screwed up.

if you type in a word that the site can't find, like "book", the menu stays normal.

The site is fine **unless** you use the search button.

The menu is getting screwed up **because** of hasTooltip.

Please let me know if there's further confusion.

Comment: The code is autogenerated? Can you not search your source files for `jQuery('.hasTooltip')` and just remove the offending line rather than put together a hack?

Comment: @jammykam, there are many, many, many files. all core files that i shouldn't be modifying anyway in first place. have already modified one file, and it works in one sense. but i can't figure out which file for this problem again. and i have already gone through a few of them, but it's just getting too much. plus, I suspect if i do some other stuff, this will rear its ugly head again since it's auto-generated though so many files! i just want it done and over with.

Comment: In that case, in the places you don't want the tooltip, remove the class `hasTooltip` from the markup you generate and the tooltip will not be applied to that element

Comment: @jammykam, how? i have no idea where it's being generated from.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm pretty convinced the issue is not the tooltip, but rather you are missing a reference to the [jQueryUI.js file for the tooltip](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/) plugin. Try adding a reference to library from [Google CDN](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide?hl=fr#jquery-ui):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

And then check your console window to make sure you have no JS errors, in Chrome press [F12]:
[image]

My guess, this error is stopping other JavaScript from running, which in turn sets up your menu.

Comment: @jammykam, dude, I could kiss you!!! thank you so much. really, you have no idea how much this was frustrating me. thank you, thank you, thank you!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @SajadLfc It just doesn't make sense otherwise! O_o

Comment: @user2730725 Glad we got there in the end

Comment: @jammykam, yes, i'm profoundly grateful that it's finally solved. thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

using [**.removeAttr()**](http://api.jquery.com/removeattr/)

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.hasTooltip').removeAttr('title');
    });
```

**OR**

using [**.removeClass()**](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/)

you can try

```
$( "#id" ).removeClass( ".hasTooltip" );
```

Comment: @user2730725 : why should you know the title for the case ?

Comment: @user2730725 : you don't need to know the title for .removeAttr()

Comment: oh, so, all I have to do is write this: `$('.hasTooltip').removeAttr('title');`?

Comment: yes. It didn't work. Darn ... I was really hoping it would work.

Comment: the page still auto-generates that dratted code ... but the jQuery code that (ie, your code) I was hoping would defang it is not working ...

Comment: atleast you will have an element with .hasTooltip class in your markup right ? show that

Comment: if I type in a word that it can't find, ie "book", the menu is fine. If I type in a word that it can find, ie, "social services", the menu gets screwed up.

Comment: really i can't get to your problem with that..!! i can't find the tooltip problem..!! i am really confused,you must provide sufficient details..!!

Comment: You **have** to use the search function that you see on top. Type in a word like "social services" Look at the menu getting messed up. Look at view source, you'll see it then.

Comment: for context, since the problem is solved now, have removed my comment that provides the link to site.

Comment: @user2730725 : ok..glad that you got it..!! Now you understood that the question was misleading..!!